# How to catch an error from express proxy to React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I used express server to be a proxy for my React, but the issue is that I cant get the error back on my react, no matter I user return next(err) or res.send(err), the last one will go to then but not catch. How can I deal with this issue ?

this is my express proxy code

```
axios({
      url:URL,
      method: "post",
      headers: header,
      data: body
    })
      .then(response => {

        res.send(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
   
        res.send(err);
        // return next(err)
      });
```

this is my React action

```
  axios
    .post("api/", body)
    .then(response => {
      console.log( response.data)

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("I want to catch the error here, but. I can't ", err);
  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the errors like this: err.response.data
In my case, I got error property from backend. So, I used err.response.data.error

My code:

```
 axios
  .get(`${API}`)
  .then(response => {
     return response.data
  })
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error.response.data.error)
  })`
```

Comment: but what I need is the display the error on React....

Answer (score 0):

This is how you catch errors when using axios post
Performing a POST request

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

your second snippet should work if `axios.post` is getting called.